# How to use Ansible service module in playbooks with limited sudo?

Tags: linux, service, sudo, ansible

I'm writing a playbook to deploy an application. I'm SSH'ing as a regular user, not root. After my application finishes deploying I want to restart its service. Obviously, to restart a service I need some sort of `sudo` privileges.

In my `/etc/sudoers` file I have:

```
redadmin ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service apache2 *
```

However, when I run my Ansible playbook it hangs when it gets to:

```
- name: Restarting apache
  service: name=apache2 state=restarted
  sudo: yes
```

How can I modify my playbook to use Ansible's `service` module without giving `redadmin` user full root privileges?

Comment: Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [sf].

Comment: This question is related to an Ansible playbook, not server setup in general. There are 88 questions with 'ansible' on SO vs 23 questions on SF.

Comment: There's no code in this question. Where's the programming angle?

Comment: @RobinGreen, please research what `Ansible` is and what its playbooks look like before you pass judgements to close questions.

Comment: Please post the programming angle in the question, if there is one.

Comment: @RobinGreen Once again, programming question is writing Ansible playbook.

Comment: Well, don't you think this question is impossible to answer without your playbook?

Comment: @RobinGreen I already posted relevant parts of my playbook!!!

Comment: The playbook is fine. The sudoers line is incompatible with ansible. You can't modify your playbook to do this. ansible doesn't support it.

Comment: @RobinGreen if you think this is the case, this should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: not really because it's not a programming question

Comment: @RobinGreen Then every single other Ansible question should closed as well.

Comment: See a discussion about this special problem at https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/5712

Comment: Since this isn't good enough for the SO people to claim it's a programming thing, I'll answer it here.

I believe what you're looking for is in Ansible 1.9 as the [become](https://gist.github.com/nanobeep/3b3d614a709086ff832a) module.